# Does using @Import annotation create all beans defined in imported file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

##### A.java:

```
@Configuration
@Import(B.class)
class A {
   @Bean
   public X x(Y y) {
       return new X(y);
   }
}
```

##### B.java:

```
@Configuration
class B {
  @Bean
  public Y y() {
     return new Y();
  }
  // And some other beans are defined
}
```

Will all beans defined in `B.java` be instantiated when bean `x` is instantiated? Since the file `B.java` is imported by `A.java`.

Answer (score 2):

First I ran the sample that is posted by you.
Then I tested one sample with following variation,

```
@Configuration
@Import(B.class)
class A {
   @Bean
   public X x(Y y) {
       return new X(y);
   }
}
```

And then the last variation as following,

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
class B {
    @Bean
    public Y y() {
        log.info("Creating bean Y in B {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
        return new Y();
    }

    @Bean
    public Z z(){
        log.info("Creating bean Z in B {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
        return new Z();
    }
    // And some other beans are defined
}
```

Here is what I inferred from my observations,

- A bean is always when you're using the annotation `@Bean`,  bean is declared from a class which is annotated with either `@Component`, `@Configuration` or `@Service` and your component class is part of your declared package in `@ComponentScan`, then Spring will always register your bean. I can safely say that @Import has very little to do with bean creation.
- Upon running second first(one with default constructor) multiple times, I found bean X created before bean Y.
- Upon running second variation where I declared more than one bean in class B, the order of bean creation was Y, X and then Z.

@Import is just used to group your bean definition source as I found here on Baeldung,
[@Import](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-import-annotation)

Answer (score 1):

### A Test:

A simple test to visualize your answer:

```java
class ATest {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);

    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(A.class);
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        for (String beanName: ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            LOGGER.info("BEAN: " + beanName);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[main] INFO be.dog.d.steven.A - BEAN: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
[main] INFO be.dog.d.steven.A - BEAN: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
[main] INFO be.dog.d.steven.A - BEAN: org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
[main] INFO be.dog.d.steven.A - BEAN: org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
[main] INFO be.dog.d.steven.A - BEAN: a
[main] INFO be.dog.d.steven.A - BEAN: org.company.B
[main] INFO be.dog.d.steven.A - BEAN: y
[main] INFO be.dog.d.steven.A - BEAN: x
```

As you can see, `@Import` did make the application context include all beans in class B as expected.

*The first 4 beans are always created, even if you use just one empty class annotated with `@Configuration` to build the application context. The fifth bean that will always be created is the annotated class used to create the context.*

### In practice:

Although this works fine, it is cleaner to have your application do a `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.company")` in a certain package or folder. This way you do not always have to add new components to the `@Import` annotation. (You might also not want to scan the whole project when you are working on a bigger project, rather just folders containing actual components.)

You can however use `@Import` on test classes to only load an isolated part of the context for that test.

You can also set the logging level of the Spring Framework to DEBUG in the **application.properties**:

```
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

This way you can also check the logs of your application to see what beans get created.

Comment: I don't get it, can you please eloborate it ? Iam new to spring. And what are the beans you are defining ?

Comment: I created a little project with all the classes you are using. In the test I create an application context using just the A.class annotated with `@configuration`. After the context is created we ask it for all bean definition names and loop over them for logging. The logs show a bean 'b' and a bean 'y' were created. So using @Import did make the application context include all beans in class B as expected.

Comment: Got it, so if I use <context:component-scan base-package="packageA"/> in my application context, and if all beans are defined in sub packages of packageA, I don't need to use any import ? and will all beans defined in 'packageA.*' (sub packages of packageA) be automatically instantiated ? Basically some beans are instantiated while running unit tests and Iam trying to find what's the reason.

Comment: That's right, that's how you would do it using xml. If you want to create a test like mine using xml you would need something like `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationcontext/user-bean-config.xml");` instead of the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(A.class);` I used. Most people prefer annotation based these days.